# Objective-C : Design tall xib over view and add to storyboard with scrollview

Tags: objective-c, xib, xcode-storyboard, reusability, xcode8

i am using Xcode 8.1

I design component for user info by xib file and add to storyboard but i have a issue

The user info is very many controls and i have to set freedom for xib

i don't know xib's height

Please step by step for me

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

could you plz add more comment in detail how do you put xib content. In further, could you try with UIView (say UIScrollView, for instance) in combination with location constrains is anchor top,left and scale right/bottom direction.
Thanks.